# Is it okay to modify the LaTeX template for article submission with additional packages?

Tags: publications, editors, latex, journal-workflow

I want to start writing on an article that is probably going to be published in one of the IOP journals. There is a template for their publications, but it lacks some (for me) essential packages. Since I've never submitted an article myself, I want to be sure the editing process goes as smooth as possible by eliminating problems early. So here's the question:

Can I add all the packages I like to the template without pissing off the editor? I talk about things like `inputenc`, `fontenc`, `biblatex`, `microtype`, etc. Nothing fancy, but very basic LaTeX stuff. I also prefer to have a separate `.bib` file for my bibliography, since I have them already organized that way and do not want to manually copy the info into the bibliography as suggested in the template.

I already read the guidelines for authors and there was no mention of modifying the template, only that its use is highly appreciated.

If anyone could provide any (preferrably inside info) on how editors work with submitted LaTeX files, that would help a lot! Thanks.

Comment: You can add packages, but you should maintain their template. You can also read various papers in the journal to see the presentation style. However, what is more important is the content of the paper itself, with less emphasis on the presentation.

Comment: **I have never met (or heard of) an editor that cares about the Latex journal templates.** Or guidelines for authors. At least in my field, I would say that you can safely ignore them. Just give them a pdf, and it's fine. If there is anything that may have an impact, it's packages that may alter the page limit (if there is one). But definitely not `inputenc`, `fontenc`, `biblatex`.

Comment: `fontenc` and `mircotype` are *essential*? They just alter the output (and will probably removed for the final publication anway…).

Comment: @Dirk well, they are of course not essential, they are just packages that I use in every document by default, so I gave them as an example. I realize that the actual typesetting is out of my hand in the final release.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Yes, with my first papers, I tried to follow the submission guidelines exactly including bibliography style, and then I discovered for the initial submission (almost?) no one cares (at least in math).

Comment: In mathematics, this is only relevant AFTER acceptance, not before.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unless explicitly forbidden, adding packages is usually ok and fully expected - e.g. in order to add support for listings, tables, symbols, encodings, operational utilities (extended macro/logic support), or specific features thereof. This should, however, never mean a general change in the appearance of the paper. Therefore, packages that globally alter fonts or font sizes are usually not allowed.

As for using a separate `.bib` file, you can usually work with that and (if explicitly requested by the guidelines - this varies a lot by publisher) copy the formatted information into the `.tex` file as late as for the camera-ready version (when nothing changes any more).

Comment: As for the last point: No need to copy something - just hand in the automatically generated .bbl-file together with the other documents of the paper.

Comment: @Dirk: Ah, probably true for IOP. I have come across some other publishers who insisted to have the bibliography right in the `.tex` file (and also some who were ok with getting a `.bib` file). I'll clarify this is publisher-dependent.

Comment: I've seen some specifications about the bibliography like you mention and restrictions about certain packages, but out of curiosity, do you know of any journals that don't allow any packages? (or any besides a small explicit subset?)

Comment: That said, add packages **only** when your paper requiers it. I have seen too many papers loading 20+ packages when all they needed was `amsmath`, which was loaded by the document class. A lot of package do thing in the backstage and can make the class not do what it should, like `enumerate` and `enumitem` (which change the typography of all counters in {enumerate}) or `inputenc` and `fontenc` (which can render the paper unreadable if you're not using the same setting as the journal and write in other language than english).

Answer (score 6):

I usually publish in IOP journals and I can confirm [O. R. Mapper's](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/73074/20058) remarks.

As an example, these are the packages included in a recent paper of mine:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{iopart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{iopams}
\usepackage{amsopn}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{listings}
```

Notice that for what concerns mathematics, there are a few idiosyncrasies related to the `iopart` class: e.g., this class is incompatible with the `amsmath` package, and it is suggested to use the `eqnarray` environment, which is otherwise deprecated. I thus suggest a careful reading of the IOP LaTeX guidelines, which can be found [here](ftp://ftp.iop.org/pub/journals/latex2e/IOPLaTeXGuidelines.pdf).

A few notes on the example above:

- The package `iopams` is an extension for `amssymb` to provide
  predefined names for bold greek letters (thanks to Barbara Beeton for
  pointing out this and Canageek for reporting it here).
- The package `subfigure` is obsolete but the the newer `subfig` package seems to be incompatible with `iopart` because it includes the `caption` package.

Comment: Correction from the TeX stack exchange, via Barbara Beeton (The expert on AMS packages): http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31170810#31170810 "there's an inaccuracy in one of the answers. iopams is stated to be an iop adaptation of amsmath. it is not. what it is, is an extension for amssymb to provide predefined names for bold greek letters. amsmath is not used at all; iop has an entirely different style for math displays."

Comment: `subfigure` is obsolete, by the way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you happen to know which font exactly IOP usually uses? I want to use the same font in my plots. The guidelines say one should stick to Helvetica, Arial and such, but I think the CM font family is more appropiate.

Comment: @cfr I know, but the newer `subfig` package seems to be incompatible with the `iopart` class because it includes the `caption` package. Thus, we used the obsolete `subfigure`.

Comment: @mwormser Unfortunately, I don't know which font they use. Notice that `iopart`, even in `twocolumn` mode yields only a lousy representation of the true article format.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano Well, then I guess I will use LM Sans for my figures and see if the journal has any issues when I submit it (someday far away in the future... :)).

Comment: Why do they suggest `eqnarray`? Isn't it all kinds of awful?

Comment: @tomasz Probably they are used to it. For a publisher, it may be easier to deal with awfulness you are familiar with than new non-awfulness.

Comment: @tomasz Moreover, as I said in a previous comment, `iopart`  yields only a lousy representation of the true article format: thus, the publisher might not be willing to keep it up to date with LaTeX developments.

Answer (score 4):

As someone who moonlights as a type-setter for a mathematical journal let me tell you something about bibliography.

Bibliography styles are different from one journal to another. There is nothing more terrible than having to reformat 60 entries by hand, and there aren't many things worse than having to reconstruct the .bib file in order to use the journal bibliography style more easily.

Sending the .bib file to the publisher is not a bad idea. If they can handle LaTeX, they can handle bibtex as well. I never worked with biblatex personally, so I can't quite tell you about that. But I do recommend that you submit you .bib file separately, and save the hassle to the type-setter.

Of course, this assumes that your .bib file wasn't hand-made. When you add an entry by hand, it has a high percentage of chance not being up to standards. Always use MathSciNet, if not then ZBMath, and if not, then Google Scholar as a last resort.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! My citations are all automatically generated/scraped, so they should be fine.

Comment: _Always use MathSciNet, if not then ZBMath, and if not, then Google Scholar as a last resort._ — ...but assume that the MathSciNet / ZBMath / Google Scholar .bib entries have errors, double-check everything against the primary sources, and fix the errors.  _Especially_ Google Scholar.

Comment: Not in math, but the same holds for acm bibtex entries. Some publishers provide their own bibtex entries for their papers (but even then verify)

Answer (score 0):

If these packages do not interfere with the paper layout than it is completely OK. However you should follow the instructions for authors style guidelines. For instance, if the template uses a specific package for generating tables, then you shouldn't change it. 
Regarding the bibliography I think that it is allowed to use bibtex and derivatives as long as the paper references style is preserved.